# Problem with creating session by AppWrite oAuth method

Tags: oauth, appwrite

I have a strange problem with logging in by Google oAuth. Everything works almost fine.
I built the same application in the web version and everything is ok. The problem occurs only in one case in the Flutter Android version.

1. I click "Login by google". The app logs me in correctly. After logging in, I check the created account with the account.get() method. It correctly returns me a User object.
2. Then again with the "Check account" button, I call again method account.get(). This time it returns a 401 error, the same when I click the "check sessions" button (it should returns the number of sessions created). Also logging out doesn't work. However, the user and sessions are created in the appwrite panel.

However, this problem only occurs if I do not have my google account data saved in the browser on the device for the first time. If I repeat the actions from above, then the next time everything will be ok, both login and logout will work.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:appwrite/appwrite.dart';
import 'package:appwrite/models.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {

  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  MyApp();

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  static const String endPoint = 'https://api.genistry.pl/v1';
  static const String projectID = '63fcc7985333af8e4dfa';
  late Client client;
  late Account account;

  String message ="";
  String action ="";

  @override
  void initState() {

    client = Client();
    account = Account(client);

    client
        .setEndpoint(endPoint) // Your API Endpoint
        .setProject(projectID);
    account = Account(client);

    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return
        MaterialApp(
            title: 'Test',
        home: Scaffold(
           body: Center(
             child: Column(
               children: [

                 SizedBox(height: 200,),
                 ElevatedButton(
                     onPressed: () async {
                       action = "Log in action";
                      var res = await account.createOAuth2Session(
                           provider: 'google',
                       );
                      var acc;
                      try {
                        acc = await account.get();
                        message = "logged: " + acc.email;
                      } catch (error) {
                          if (error is AppwriteException)   message = error.message!;
                      }
                      setState(() {});
                     },
                     child: Text ("Login by google")
                 ),

                 ElevatedButton(
                     onPressed: () async {
                       action = "Get account info action";
                       var acc;
                       try {
                         acc = await account.get();
                         message = "logged: " + acc.email;
                       } catch (error) {
                         if (error is AppwriteException)   message = error.message!;
                       }
                       setState(() {});
                     },
                     child: Text ("Check account")
                 ),

                 ElevatedButton(
                     onPressed: () async {
                       action = "Session check action";
                       SessionList ses;
                       try {
                         ses = await account.listSessions();
                         message = "Sessions count: " + ses.sessions.length.toString();
                       } catch (error) {
                         if (error is AppwriteException)   message = error.message!;
                       }
                       setState(() {});
                     },
                     child: Text ("check sessions")
                 ),

                 ElevatedButton(
                     onPressed: () async {
                       action = "Logout action";
                       var res;
                       try {
                         res = await account.deleteSession(sessionId: 'current');
                         message = "You are logout";
                       } catch (error) {
                         if (error is AppwriteException)   message = error.message!;
                       }
                       setState(() {});
                     },
                     child: Text ("Logout")
                 ),

                 SizedBox(height: 60),
                 Text (action),
                 Text (message)

               ],
             ),
           ),
         )

        );

  }
}
```

Comment: I also facing similar

When I do Google auth it works fine like you said sessions are also created in admin panel, when I call account.get() it's return user data there was no problem even i believe logout was also working "when i call it's deleted session for admin panel".

But the problem in oAuth2 it's return null response also after creating the user when I tried to create document it's thrown error message that

This user doesn't have a permission 401 errors code. (Look like appwrite doesn't know user is already logged in or not)